# uiautomator assert multiple times

Tags: java, assert, assertions, android-uiautomator

I am running tests with uiautomator. When I get to the end of my test, I need to test my results. My problem is of one test fails, the others will not be tested. I need them all to be tested regardless of the results of other test. This is my attempts:

```
public void testSomeUI() {
  ////lots of stuff

  assertEquals(///assertion///);
  assertEquals(///assertion///);
  assertEquals(///assertion///);
  ....and so on
}
```

Also I tried:

```
public void testSomeUI() {
  ////lots of stuff

 testValue1();
 testValue2();
 testValue3();
  ....and so on
}

  private void testValue1(){
   assertEquals(///assertion///);
}  
  private void testValue2(){
   assertEquals(///assertion///);
}   
  private void testValue3(){
   assertEquals(///assertion///);
} 
..and so on
```

If one fails, the last three won't run. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that once an assert fails, it breaks out of the method. That's why the rest don't get run.

Try using a test framework like JUnit (which UIAutomator appears to be built on). Then write one method per assert. That way will you not only get all asserts to run every time, you also break down the tests into suitably small sizes. If they're named properly, you may not need to debug at all, since you can tell by name of the failing test where the problem really is.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html)'s a link to a tutorial for example.

Comment: I know what causes it, as I stated in my question. And I also tried using multiple methods, as I showed in my question...

Comment: You're calling them all from the same method though, so once you break out of it, the rest don't get called.

Comment: I see. So I will need to add those test to the runtest script?

Comment: You can use `setUp()` to run your UI script and then put the asserts in `public void testSomething()` methods that are each run separately after the `setUp()` is done.

Comment: Thats what I mean by my runtest script